# How to Handle Scrollview Slow Android

Tags: android, scrollview, nestedscrollview

im used two recyclerview in one layout, and if i want to both recylerview can scroll, i adding Nested Scrollview.

Maybe like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/NestedScrollView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/xx"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/arrayListUser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:divider="@color/white">


        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@color/line"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/arrayList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:divider="@color/white">


        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

two Recylerview in one Nestedscrollview make slow scroll. so, how to handle to make it fast?

Comment: Refer this Answer it will help u :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41956464/3946958 ..Let me know in case of concern

Answer (score 2):

set [setNestedScrollingEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html) to false

```
    mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

and also in the layout

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        ...
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>
```

Which Enables or disables nested scrolling for this view.

Comment: NestedScrollview can't detect

Comment: Can you post the complete stackTrace line here?